# What is our stance on edits that only add one or several tags?

Tags: discussion, editing

What is our stance on edits that only add one or several tags? Should they be accepted or rejected?

Examples: [accepted edit](https://biology.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/58390); [rejected edit](https://biology.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/58497).

Comment: I think it;'s quite simple; if the tags are relevant - accept, otherwise reject.

Comment: In this case it was my rejection and I was probably too quick to reject; I saw only the minor text edits that made no improvement and missed the comment and tag addition. Ordinarily I would accept such an edit.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that edits that only add one or several tags should be accepted. Copying the comments in case they get deleted:

> - I think it's quite simple; if the tags are relevant - accept, otherwise reject. – AliceD♦ ↵ yesterday
> - I would accept such an edit. – Bryan Krause♦ ↵ 18 hours ago